# VBA Code adding incorrect column rows for sub-totals

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to update a previous employees code. 
Column D and E are not adding the correct sub-totals. It seems for each sub total row, it is counting A4 which is the first row of numbers.

Not sure how to adjust the code.

```
Set firstSub = Range("D" & cTL.Row) 'set first sum from

For Each c In Range("D" & cTL.Row, "D" & cBR.Row)
    If c.Value2 = "" Then
        c.ClearContents
    End If
    'This if will only run for column D, but will fill column D and E with total fields
    If Right(c.Offset(0, -2).Value2, Len(sTotal)) = sTotal Then
        c.FormulaR1C1 = "=sum(R" & firstSub.Row & "C" & c.Column & ":R" & c.Offset(-1, 0).Row & "C" & c.Column & ")"
        c.Offset(0, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=sum(R" & firstSub.Row & "C" & c.Offset(0, 1).Column & ":R" & c.Offset(-1, 0).Row & "C" & c.Offset(0, 1).Column & ")"
        formulaStrD = formulaStrD & c.Address([], [], xlR1C1) & ","
        formulaStrE = formulaStrD & c.Offset(0, 1).Address([], [], xlR1C1) & ","
    ElseIf Right(Range("A" & c.Row), Len(sTotal)) = sTotal Then
        formulaStrD = Left(formulaStrD, Len(formulaStrD) - 1)
        formulaStrE = Left(formulaStrE, Len(formulaStrE) - 1)
        c.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(" & formulaStrD & ")"
        c.Offset(0, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(" & formulaStrE & ")"
    End If
Next c

For Each c In Range("E" & cTL.Row, "H" & cBR.Row)
    If c.Value2 = "" Then
        c.ClearContents
    End If
Next c

End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54634305/edit) to explain what the correct subtotal should be, what it is right now and which values should be ignored?

Comment: There seems to be a disconnect with how this is creating the subtotal rows for columns D and E (e.g. rows 4, 7, 17, etc.). It doesn't seem to actually be looking for start/end rows for the changing values in column B.

Comment: Isn't it essentially creating running-totals, located only under each category? (Including the prior "sub-totals".... apparently.)

Comment: @Mistella -  I read the data (via the labels) as sub-totals by column B with totals by column A - but you are correct, the code looks like each sub-total by column B is including the prior sub-totals.

Comment: On a side note - the formula for column E's total refers to column D: `formulaStrE = formulaStrD & c.Offset(0, 1).Address([], [], xlR1C1) & ","` .. I am guessing that should be `formulaStrE = formulaStrE & c.Offset(0, 1).Address([], [], xlR1C1) & ","`

Comment: Excel has a built-in subtotal function for exactly this purpose, why not try calling and using that?

Comment: The gray rows should equal the total amounts of that specific DIV.

Comment: @Mistella correct,  but I am unsure how to edit the VB code.

Comment: @Selkie - the `SUBTOTAL` would be preferred, I think, if the rows between the DIV values were fixed. Or are you suggesting use of `SUBTOTAL` in the FormulaR1C1 vs. `SUM`? Or are you meaning to use the feature-rich subtotal operation in Excel where you can specify column aggregates and it creates collapsible row groupings?

Comment: @Forty3: The third one - where you can specify column aggregates and it creates collapsible row groupings. This looks like a textbook example of when it's needed, and why do things the hard way when there's an easy, built-in method?

Comment: I do apologize if the question is not worded correctly, but I have not used VB and Macros in years and I am very rusty. I need to change the DIV value sub totals within the code source.

Answer (score 0):

The key to fixing this (I think) is to 'reset' the "first row" each time the value in column B changes - otherwise, each sub-total for each distinct value in column B will reflect the aggregate of all rows above it - including the other sub-totals.

```vb
Set firstSub = Range("D" & cTL.Row) 'set first sum from

For Each c In Range("D" & cTL.Row, "D" & cBR.Row)
    If c.Value2 = "" Then
        c.ClearContents
    End If
    'This if will only run for column D, but will fill column D and E with total fields
    If Right(c.Offset(0, -2).Value2, Len(sTotal)) = sTotal Then
        c.FormulaR1C1 = "=sum(R" & firstSub.Row & "C" & c.Column & ":R" & c.Offset(-1, 0).Row & "C" & c.Column & ")"
        c.Offset(0, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=sum(R" & firstSub.Row & "C" & c.Offset(0, 1).Column & ":R" & c.Offset(-1, 0).Row & "C" & c.Offset(0, 1).Column & ")"
        formulaStrD = formulaStrD & c.Address([], [], xlR1C1) & ","
        ' Fix the Column E subtotal reference
        formulaStrE = formulaStrE & c.Offset(0, 1).Address([], [], xlR1C1) & ","

        ' Reset the "firstRow" so that we don't accidentally pickup
        ' the other subtotals
        Set firstSub = c.Offset(1, 0)

    ElseIf Right(Range("A" & c.Row), Len(sTotal)) = sTotal Then
        formulaStrD = Left(formulaStrD, Len(formulaStrD) - 1)
        formulaStrE = Left(formulaStrE, Len(formulaStrE) - 1)
        c.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(" & formulaStrD & ")"
        c.Offset(0, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(" & formulaStrE & ")"

        ' Reset the subtotal formulas along with the "firstRow"
        formulaStrD = ""
        formulaStrD = ""
        Set firstSub = c.Offset(1, 0)

    End If
Next c

For Each c In Range("E" & cTL.Row, "H" & cBR.Row)
    If c.Value2 = "" Then
        c.ClearContents
    End If
Next c
```

Comment: This worked like a charm. Thank you for helping with this. I understand the changes.